# If you add more coils around a spinning magnet does it produce more electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

If you have a magnet spinning at 1800RPM and put multiple coils next to it does it produce more electricity than if you only put one coil next to it? Will more coils require more energy input to keep it spinning at 1800RPM due to Lenz's Law? So, would two coils produce the same amount of electricity as one coil with the same energy input into spinning the magnet?

Comment: You're going to have to quantify what you mean by "electricity" whether you mean voltage, current, or just plain old energy. Yes, more turns does produce more voltage. If you hook something across the output terminals of the coils so that increase in voltage also results in an increase in current, then that means more energy which means that will require more torque because no free lunch.

Comment: Additionally, the rate of rotation makes no differnce to DKNguyen's comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to build an alternator (an AC generator). Quite a few very good designs do exist, serving a wide diversity of purposes and you can learn from them.

Otherwise, your question has a lot of variables unaccounted for.

- the magnet size, shape, strength
- coils geometry, placement and resistance
- the load properties (resistance in the first place)

And, using something as basic as the energy conservation, you can assume that the energy input (manifesting as torque, since you are thinking about a constant RPM) would depend on the electric power produced (including the power loss in the coil resistance).

Your magnet-and-coils construct will radiate some electromagnetic energy as well. It is also dependent on the above unknown variables and will also impose some torque on the magnet shaft.

Answer (score -1):

If there are more coils, the field generated by these coils at the magnet position and therefore the braking torque on the magnet will be greater: it will therefore be necessary to provide more work to rotate the magnet: no miracle!

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote ? And I'm sure my ideas on the subject are correct !